# How with action in modal dialog to update state of fields of editor page?

Tags: laravel-filament

In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app I use getHeaderActions() with modal dialog to make an action on the current row
and changing status and some fields of this row :

```php
->action(function (array $data, array $arguments): void {
    if ( ! empty($data['department_id']) and ! empty($data['job_start'])) {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            UserJobDepartmentCandidate::create([
                'user_id'              => $this->record->id,
                ...
            ]);

            $this->record->status = UserMeeting::USER_MEETING_STATUS_JOB_POSITION_WAS_PROPOSED;
            $this->record->updated_at = Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
            $this->record->save();
            DB::commit();
    Notification::make()
        ->title('This user was accepted for job. !')
        ->success()
        ->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
        }

    }
})
```

but how can I update state of fields of $this->record, without page reloading ?

**Updated :**

$this->record - that is model in parent form.
I found how method refreshFormData works at https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/pages#refreshing-form-data docs

but refreshing 'updated_at' field it value as it keeps in db “2023-11-10T09:32:54+02:00”
but I need to show formatted value as “10 November, 2023 9:36 AM”, as I define text input :

```
TextInput::make('updated_at')
    ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) {
        $UserMeetingModel = $component->getModelInstance();
        $component->state(DateConv::getFormattedDateTime(
            $UserMeetingModel->getAttribute('updated_at'),
            \App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT
        ));
    })->disabled()
    ->hidden(fn(?UserMeeting $record
    ) => ($record === null or $record->getAttribute('updated_at') === null))
    ->label('Updated at'),
```

where DateConv::getFormattedDateTime method for formatting of date and \App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT which format must be
used. If there is a way with refreshFormData to trigger method afterStateHydrated ?

Comment: I don'understand where *$this->record* comes from, but *$this->refreshFormData([/\* attributes\*/])* should suit your needs